# Can all knot polynomials derived from Skein relations be categorified?

Tags: knot-theory, ct.category-theory

Can all knot polynomials derived from Skein relations be categorified?

Comment: Can the categorified Jones polynomial be derived from skein relations?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. "Can" as in "there is no obstruction in principle", or "can" as in "has been"?